# Spring integrtion mqtt and JPA transaction

Tags: transactions, spring-integration, mqtt

### Context:

I have a Spring Integration flux managing data coming from a MQTT broker.

I use a MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter to get the messages from mqtt.

All the processing are done in a single thread (MQTT thread), I am not using any poller.

I am using JPA/Hibernate/MySQL

### The problem I am facing

The mqtt event processing flow involve multiple transformers and routers, but create multiple transactions.

### Question

How can I create a uniq transaction to process every mqtt message?
I am using Java config.

Thanks for your help.

An extract of my config:

```
@Bean
public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter rak7249ChannelAdapter(
        MqttConfig rak7249MqttConfig, 
        MqttPahoClientFactory rak7249MqttClientFactory, 
        MessageChannel rak7249Channel,
        MqttRak7249Converter mqttRak7249Converter) {
    var adapter = ConfigUtils.mqttChannelAdapter("application/+/device/+/+", rak7249MqttConfig, rak7249MqttClientFactory, rak7249Channel, mqttRak7249Converter);

    return adapter;
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = rak7249Channel, outputChannel = loraChannel)
public Rak7249FluxLoraTransformer rak7249ToLoraMessageTransformer(Rak7249Service service) {
    return new Rak7249FluxLoraTransformer(service);
}

@Bean
@Splitter(inputChannel = loraChannel)
public AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean<AbstractMessageSplitter> loraSplitter(LoraService service, MessageChannel mixedLoraChannel) {
    return new AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean<AbstractMessageSplitter>() {

        @Override
        protected AbstractMessageSplitter createHandler() {
            var splitter = new LoraMessageSplitter(service);
            splitter.setOutputChannel(mixedLoraChannel);
            return splitter;
        }
    };
}

@Bean
@Router(inputChannel = mixedLoraChannel)
public PayloadTypeRouter mixedLoraRouter() {

    var router = new PayloadTypeRouter();
    router.setChannelMapping(ThingEncodedMessage.class.getName(), thingEncodedDataChannel);
    router.setChannelMapping(LoraMetricMessage.class.getName(), loraMetricChannel);

    return router;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = loraMetricChannel)
public MessageHandler writeLoraMetric(WriteInfluxDB influxDB, WriteSQL sql) {
    return new AbstractMessageHandler() {

        @Override
        @Transactional
        protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> imessage) {
            sql.writePoint(imessage);

            // Not a transactional resource
            influxDB.writePoint(imessage);
        }
    };
}
```

... and so on

Comment: You need to show your code and configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell , I did add an extract of my java config, and update the problem description. tks.

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` to the adapter bean definition does nothing; that is simply a bean definition. The `@Transactional` on the service method should work fine, that's when the transaction will start; what does your "// Not transactional" comment mean? I don't see "multiple transactions" there.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help.
The Not transactional comment point out that the influxDB resource is not part of the transaction.

But the flux involve other services which are transactional.
Now, each service run in a separate transaction. I'd like to run everything in one single tx, one transaction per mqtt message.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "transactional gateway"; easiest to describe using the Java DSL:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So68913184Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68913184Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
        options.setUserName("guest");
        options.setPassword("guest".toCharArray());
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound(MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory) {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("siSampleConsumer",
                mqttClientFactory, "siSampleTopic");
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow(MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound, TransactionalGateway gate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound)
                .transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT")
                .log()
                .handle(msg -> gate.sendIntransaction(msg))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(Service service) {
        return f -> f.handle(service);
    }

}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mainFlow.input")
interface TransactionalGateway {

    @Transactional
    void sendIntransaction(Message<?> msg);

}

@Component
class Service {

    public void process(Message<?> msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

Everything downstreamm of the gateway (on the same thread) runs in the same transaction.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for your help Gary.